# How can I structure an Express+React TypeScript project well?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, express, directory-structure

I am currently trying to set up a project that uses Express for the backend and React for the frontend. I also want to use TypeScript for both parts. For easy setup, I used `npx create-react-app client --template typescript` and `npx express-generator-typescript server`, resulting in the following directory structure:

```
myProjectRoot/
|_ server/
   |_ src/
   |_ node_modules/
   |_ package.json
   |_ tsconfig.json
   |_ ...
|_ client/
   |_ src/
   |_ node_modules/
   |_ package.json
   |_ tsconfig.json
   |_ ...
```

Now I configured React’s development server in `client/package.json` with a line `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"` and let the Express server listen on port `3001` to handle API requests. So far, so good; for development, this is perfectly fine imho.

However, I am a bit confused how to best set up the commands for a production build. I wanted to change the default-configured build directories to avoid having client and server build each in an isolated directory:

```
myProjectRoot/
|_ server/
   |_ ...
   |_ src/
   |_ dist/
      |_ compiled_backend_code
|_ client/
   |_ ...
   |_ src/
   |_ build/
      |_ compiled_frontend_code
```

Instead, I aimed for something like this because it seems much cleaner to me:

```
myProjectRoot/
|_ server/
|_ client/
|_ dist/
   |_ server/
      |_ compiled_backend_code
   |_ client
      |_ compiled_frontend_code
```

To get there, I changed the `outDir` of the server’s `tsconfig.json` to `../dist/server` and the `build` script in the client’s `package.json` to `react-scripts build && mv build ../dist/client` (as explained [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1354#issuecomment-299956790)).

The problem with this now is that the compiled code does not find its dependencies any more because the server’s and client’s `node_modules` folders are not located in the `dist/` directory or a parent directory any more. I’m not sure what a good solution to this problem is, so I’d appreciate any input, even if it means a completely different project structure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two ways that I know of:

1. Keeping client build folder inside client root, and then addressing it like in [this example](https://github.com/rok-tel/ts-express-react/blob/947dfb3de23c63563a9c8c38867a8d63a09904f2/packages/server/src/index.ts#L19).
2. Use [Yarn Workspaces](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/), where `node_modules` are mainly in the root folder (except for when packages are using different versions of the same dependency)

BTW, this repo is a boilerplate I've created for a full stack Express + React Web application in Typescript using [Yarn Workspaces](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/).